# UK inheritance tax for Jersey-born British passport holder living overseas?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, inheritance, estate-planning, expatriate

I was born in Jersey, where there is no inheritance tax. I have a full British passport which doesn’t have the page about being a crown protectorate because it was issued in Beijing. I have never been tax resident in the UK, but I do own some UK stocks and and isle-of-man Investment-Linked Policy (big mistake, but that’s another post…). I now live in Singapore where there is also no inheritance tax. I do not have a will in the UK, Singapore, or Jersey.

Will my estate be liable for UK inheritance tax when all those sticks of satay finally catch up with me?